# Change App languages based on Locale using the new support libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library

i used to change the language in the app
by doing the following :

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lang))
        cfg.locale = new Locale(lang);
    else
        cfg.locale = Locale.getDefault();

    Resources resources = ctx.getResources();
    resources.updateConfiguration(cfg, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

and then restart the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

this way was working fine however after i have changed the support libraries version from  `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

To `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'`

the the resources doesn't change unless i kill the app

I wrote a sample [here](https://github.com/samerzmd/AndroidChangeLanguageProblem) that demonstrate the problem with a dummy solution that restart the app through the alarm manager, yet i believe that i might be doing something wrong or i missed something wrote in the release notes [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

i have searched a lot but i haven't found anything about this problem,
the only new issue i have found related to the resources was mention in [commonsware's blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/09/random-musings-n-developer-preview.html)

which's about the new android N as it's says:

> if you are one of those developers who has been overriding the user’s device locale within your app… test thoroughly on N, please.

yet my probelm is in Lollipop,kitkat and jelly beans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code is working fine for me.
I am storing language in preferance and using following code I am able to make app in multi language.

```
Locale locale;
switch (userPreference.language)
    {
        default:
        case 0:
            locale = new Locale("de");
            languageCode = "de-de";
            break;

        case 1:
            locale = new Locale("en");
            languageCode = "en-en";
            break;

        case 2:
            locale = new Locale("fr");
            languageCode = "fr-fr";
            break;

        case 3:
            locale = new Locale("pl");
            languageCode = "pl-pl";
            break;
    }

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

please look below code of my activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UserPreference userPreference = PreferenceHelper.getUserPreference(context);
    switch (userPreference.language)
    {
        case 0:
            GenericHelper.changeLanguage(context, "de");
            break;
        case 1:
            GenericHelper.changeLanguage(context, "en");
            break;
        case 2:
            GenericHelper.changeLanguage(context, "fr");
            break;
        case 3:
            GenericHelper.changeLanguage(context, "pl");
            break;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_signature);
```

Comment: it's the same as mine,
try to change the support library version to 
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
and it will not work

Comment: actually i am using appcompact-v7 but it is working for me. I have done check for language from preferance in each screen and then apply above code before 'setcontentview();'

Comment: please check I have edited my answer with my on create

Comment: do you use v7:23.2.1 ?? if not then i believe if you changes to that then it will not work.
try to use build the sample if you could

http://imgur.com/H9n9yYA

Comment: in my case all data taken from string.xml file

Comment: if you do the edit in the gradle files which is in the image i believe you would have the problem 

i also take it from strings.xml (with respect to local of course -ar,-fr....etc)

Comment: I am using buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: change to 23.2.1 and you would have the issue

Comment: Hmm.. you apply the configuration  to the current context before setting the content, unlike me i apply it to an old context and then starts new one.
somehow the method i use was working before the new support libraries.
after i updated the sample with the your way it's now working,